# convert/copy from arraylist to object array

Tags: java

I have an arraylist at the start of my class

```
private ArrayList<Dog> dogs;
```

This is how dog is declared in the dog class

```
public Dog(String name, ArrayList<Owner> owners, boolean likeBones, String food,
        int mealsPerDay);
```

I am trying to find the dogs who like bones and save that dog into result. The rest of the code works fine including .getLikesBones().

```
Dog[] result = null;
for (Dog dogSearch : dogs) {

        if (dogSearch.getLikesBones()){ 
            result =dogSearch; //I know this won't work, just simply showing what I want.
        }



    }
    return result;
}
```

thank you in advance for all help.

Comment: It didn't work is not a good explanation of your issue... Are you getting a nullpointerexception right? Think about it.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. You should probably try and implement the stuff you studied so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may not know the `result` size. So, `result` should be declared as `ArrayList` instead of array. Look at below code.

```
List<Dog> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

Than add the search value into `result`.

```
for (Dog dogSearch : dogs) {
  if (dogSearch.getLikesBones()){ 
     result.add(dogSearch);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection instead of using an array

```
List<Dog> result = new ArrayList<Dog>();
for (Dog dogSearch : dogs) {
        if (dogSearch.getLikesBones()){ 
             result.add(dogSearch);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked great. Just had to change the method to public List<Dog> and had to import java.util.List;

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you change `Dog[] result` to `List<Dog> result = new ArrayList<>()`, so you can add data without worrying on initializing the array at a fixed size.

Your code would look like this:

```
List<Dog> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Dog dogSearch : dogs) {
    if (dogSearch.getLikesBones()){ 
        result.add(dogSearch);
    }
}
return result;
```

If you still need to return `Dog[]` rather than `List<Dog>`, then call `List#toArray` at the `return` statement:

```
return result.toArray(new Dog[result.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways of doing this. you have declared a `regular array of Dogs` at the top of your code.

To do it with the `regular array` you will need to declare an `int` to hold the index of the array since there is no "add" function for regular arrays. So it would be :

```
Dog[] result = new Dog[dogs.lenght()];
int index = 0;
for (Dog dogSearch : dogs) {

        if (dogSearch.getLikesBones()){ 
            result[index] = dogSearch;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

otherwise use an array list of dogs for the "result" and just do

`arrayList.Add(dogSearch);`

Comment: fails to allocate memory for result array.

Comment: how about initializing an array?

Comment: hmm.. I thought theres a way to declare array without specifying size... looking now

Comment: There is, it's called `ArrayList` :P  If you insist on using an array for the result allocate one to be as large as it might need to be.  Which in this case is `dogs.length()`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Dog> result = new ArrayList<Dog>();
for (Dog dogSearch : dogs) {

    if (dogSearch.getLikesBones()){ 
        result.put(dogSearch); 
    }

}
return result; }
```